# VS Code - Create keyboard shortcuts for bold, italics, underline

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

First, I know all about how Emmet can wrap text inside whatever. And I know how to map a keyboard shortcut to invoke Emmet's wrapping. But, I am looking for something quicker.

In VS Code, how do create a keyboard shortcut for wrapping HTML text inside a `strong` tag, for example? Let's say you wanna map it to `cmd-alt-b`.

In Sublime Text this is how it's done:

`{"keys": ["option+super+b"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<strong>${1:$SELECTION}</strong>$0"}}`

What would be the VS Code equivalency?

Comment: I think this works, but unsure if it's proper: `{
  "key": "cmd+alt+b",
  "scope": "javascript,html,php,njk",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
   "snippet": "<strong>${1:$SELECTION}</strong>$0"
  }
 }`

Comment: You can simplify a bit: `"snippet": "<strong>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</strong>$0"` (unless you want the selected text still selected in order to possibly overwrite3 ) and while `$SELECTION` seems to work, it isn't listed as a snippet variable at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables so you should switch to `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT`.

Answer (score 36):

***This is a fully detailed answer about how to wrap a selected word with a shortcut.***

### Open keybindings.json file

Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on macOS) to open Keyboard Shortcuts tab.

Then click on the JSON icon to open the keybindings.json file.

[image: Click on the JSON icon]

### Choose the right binding

Naturally, to put a text in bold, the most appropriate keyboard shortcut is `ctrl+b`. However, this keyboard shortcut may collide with another.

You can check that the shortcut is safe by searching for your shortcut in the search bar.

[image: Search for your shortcut in the search bar]

As you can see on the picture, for a HTML file, when a text is selected, there is no major collision except the Toggle Side Bar shortcut which will not work when a text is selected in a HTML file. But it is not a problem, deselect the text and you will now be able to toggle the VS Code side bar.

### Place your key binding

Once the file is open, insert your JSON key binding inside the brackets.

Here is mine, which will wrap the words selected with the  tag :

```json
{
    "key":"ctrl+b",
    "scope":"html",
    "command":"editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when":"editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'html'",
    "args":{
        "snippet":"<strong>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</strong>$0"
    }
}
```

You can wrap the wrapping tag with the the desired one.

Save the file and open a HTML file, then select a word and press `ctrl+b`, your word will be automatically wrapped with the  tag.

Hope my answer helped you